# C++ count member function overloading

Tags: c++, c++17

#### **Q** : Is there a way to implement a type trait that counts identically named member function ?

The base mecanism would be to get a `template-parameter-pack` from a single function/member-function ref/ptr syntax,
which contains possible overloads - *that seems not possible to me without additional boilerplate*.

Here is a hypothetical syntax :

```cpp
// impl

template <typename>
struct count_function_overloads
{
   constexpr static bool value = /**/;
};
template <typename T>
constexpr static auto count_overloads_v = count_overloads<T>::value;

// usage

struct A {
   void func(int);
   void func(char, float);
};
static_assert(count_overloads_v<decltype(&A::func)> == 2);
```

Comment: May I ask about the purpose you plan to use that?

Comment: Would this return infinity: `struct Infinite { template<typename T> void func(T); };`? You could use it to solve Fermat's Last Theorem: `struct Fermat{ template<int X, int Y, int Z, int N, std::enable_if<(2<N)&&power(X,N)+power(Y,N)==power(Z,N),int>> void func(); };`

Comment: when we get reflection you can count the members with the same name.

Comment: @RaymondChen I'd think because `decltype` of such function/member function does not work, create a SFINAE rule to avoid such usage.

Comment: @BobBills Seems like you're right, but trying to implement so-called "impossible" stuff is always a great source of knowledge to me.  
I remember a talk from Herb Sutter about a meta-languages proposal that allows some kind of introspection/reflexion that sounds both scary and interesting.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Basically, improve some function_traits implementations,  
as well as some detection idioms implementation mecanism

Comment: @Guss Hmm, can't ypu restrict the hirarchy using [`final`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) specifiers in the classes themselves?

Comment: @Guss -- Realize that some existing traits are impossible to implement "by hand" using standard C++, and are actually compiler intrinsics.  Maybe this is the territory where you're treading -- trying to implement something that is impossible without compiler help.